# Is there any number which $n!$ is lower than $2^n$ or same?

Tags: factorial

I interested in this question.
how many numbers meet this condition?
I think a few of them meet this but I want a proof for this.
also I'm not very pro in mathematics.

Comment: You want to know when $n! \le 2^n$? For $n \in \mathbb{N}$? 

It's $n=0,1,2,3.$ That's it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $n!<2^n$  if $n<4$ and $n!>2^n$ for $n=4$

Let $m!>2^m$ for $m\ge 4$

Then  $(m+1)!>(m+1)2^m>2^{m+1}$ if $m+1\ge 2\iff m\ge1$ which is true as  $m\ge 4$

Comment: OP, this is called a "proof by induction".

Comment: yes. a good proof that noobs can know some of it mean too!

Answer (score 3):

This is a good time to just "plug-and-play" with values of $n$. There will be only a handful that meet this condition:

Namely, when and only when $n = 0, 1, 2, 3$, then we have $n! \leq 2^n$. For a valid proof of this, plug in and test out $n = 0, n = 1, n = 2, and n = 3$ to confirm.

Challenge: Use proof by induction on $n$ to prove that for all values of $$n \geq 4 \implies n! \gt 2^n$$

Comment: Needs another UV +1

Answer (score 0):

This condition will hold for all $n$ from $0$ up to $3$, then $n! > 2^n$ for all $n > 3$

Answer (score 0):

[You can see the Gamma function $\Gamma(x+1)$ (which is the extension to the reals of the factorial $x!$) intercepts $2^x$ at $x\approx 3.46$. After this it is always greater.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%28x%2B1%29%3D2%5Ex)